# How to fix 'IllegalStateException' (fatal exception) in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio and trying to build a calculator which performs addition. On executing the app on my phone  there is an error which says 'IllegalStateException' and there is a message displayed on my phone saying that has app has stopped working. Some help please.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void onButtonClick(View v) throws IllegalStateException
    {
        EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view);
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
        int RESULT = num1+num2;
        t1.setText(Integer.toString(RESULT));

    }
}
```

The stack trace after running after entering the values

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

2019-07-16 11:02:03.122 14400-14400/com.example.calculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.calculator, PID: 14400
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5675)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22646)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5675) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22646) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1075) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:22)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5675) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22646) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1075) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be better if you add the complete error stack trace in the question as only `IllegalStateException` wouldn't help anybody to advise you on the problem.

Comment: R.id.view is of type view and not of type TextView. Change R.id.view to a textview

Comment: You haven't declared and implemented the code correclty! Refer to some android tutorials for a better understanding online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.TextView at
>   com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:22)

in this line:

```
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view);
```

because `R.id.view` is the id of a `View`, not a `TextView` (check your layout xml).

You need to make that view a textview in your layout file.

Comment: I changed it to a textview and now it works perfectly. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void onButtonClick(View view){
    EditText e1 = view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText e2 = view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    TextView t1 = view.findViewById(R.id.view);
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    int result = num1+num2;
    t1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
}
```

}